# Is [spell-components] description correct?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

> [spell-components](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spell-components)
>
> Physical items that are required for use in the casting of certain types of spells.

By the description, it seems the tag refers to only spell material components, and excludes verbal and somatic components.

However, the questions using this tag seem to correctly include verbal, somatic, and material components of a spell.

**What should we put in the description to correctly include all components of a spell?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably something like this instead:

> For questions about the components that go into spells, or how they get involved in spellcasting. In Dungeons & Dragons, those components are usually materials, words, and/or motions.

The tag wiki excerpt's main job is to guide people in how and when to use the tag, and to help them work out whether the tag fits the question they might apply it to, so I'm frontloading that. After that, we can summarise what it usually means in brief. Tag wiki excerpts don't need to define a thing thoroughly, so I'm just doing a general indicator in brief; the second sentence would be totally optional.

Comment: I think this is a good summary! I edited the wording slightly; hopefully you agree that it's an improvement.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the tag info with this suggestion, since I don't really see a downside (in the worst case, the suggested edit would simply not be approved).

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks very much for doing that.